# How to remove executable JavaScript from a QueryString variable?

Tags: javascript, query-string

I have a page URL something like this: https://site.com/page.aspx?QSVariableName=Value

Our security team has raised a vulnerability stating that if the Value portion is injected with executable JS, that is something like:

https://site.com/page.aspx?QSVariableName=Value%27%2balert%281234567890%29%2b%27 (Equivalent to passing *Value'+alert(1234567890)+'*)

Then *1234567890* is alerted from the OnClick event of a hyperlink I have on the page that uses Value.

Like I said, this is not something I am doing intentionally, but is identified as a vulnerability in the code. So the question is, how do I make sure QSVariableName uses just the Value and ignore unnecessary code (lets keep to JS only for now)?

The complexity that comes to my mind is QSVariableName could contain ANY JS code, not just alert(). And it could be present anywhere, not just at the end. Is there any way to identify JS executable code embedded in a string?

It is OK if Value is a bad 'string' as long as it doesn't contain anything executable.

Comment: Can we see the code where you read and use `QSVariableName` in the script?  It might help us to see how your code is reading and executing JS directly from the query string.

Comment: As you're using asp.net, you should read about [How to prevent XSS (Cross Site Scripting)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649310.aspx)

Comment: Citizenslave, I can't share the exact code... but here is the idea. There is QSVariableName=Value in the URL. There is a hyperlink on the page whose OnClick event is set to call a JS function by passing 'Value' as one of the params. Per my edited description, 1234567890 is being alerted even before the first line of the JS function is invoked, mostly because the param value itself contains executable JS. So I need to figure out a way to chop off that unnecessary code even before calling the OnClick event. So a C# method that identifies valid JS in a string variable is what I am looking for.

Comment: Sergio, I like the article you presented. It is exactly what I am talking about. I am looking to "Constrain Input". However I am not sure how to apply the RegEx validation to my Value that could be a combination of characters, special symbols, numbers. Some valid values are: ctl00_Main_Component1234, ctl00_Footer_Component9876. Even if I come up with a RegEx to match something like ctl00_*_Component#, how do I detect JS inside *?

Answer (score 0):

What if, instead of putting `QSVariableName` directly into the `onclick` attribute, you used a `switch/case` pattern to choose a function based on `QSVariableName`?  You could also map appropriate query strings to appropriate functions using an associative array.  Either way, you'd only ever be treating `QSVariableName` as a string and only be using safe and pre-approved JS in your `onclick` event.  The downside being, anyone who tries to inject JS into the query string will get an error, but they're trying to hack your site...their user experience should suffer accordingly.

Without seeing more of your code, I'm not sure I can come up with a better answer...